# How do I load same css and scripts as dashboard, in my wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I have googled this and looked across this site and for the life of me cannot find an answer,

I am writing a plugin for wordpress and when I log into the dashboard I can see a collapsable div with content all styled nicely.

When I open my plugin page I don't see the same styles even though the page is very basic.

I have copied the code from the dashboard but it seems as though some of the styles are missing.

I do not need to add custom styles or scripts I just want to load the same css as the dashboard page.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? I assume that the plugin page will adopt the standard admin css, is this assumption wrong?

Comment: The same css ans js is available in your plugin (in the dashboard) as the rest of the dashboard.  Check your html classes, etc.  WP uses specific classes for most of the admin elements, which gives it the look/feel you are trying to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to load anything extra for this, just use the correct classes. 
You can either look these up in the source, or by using resources as this:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/07/01/how-to-design-and-style-your-wordpress-plugin-admin-panel/